# Rails accepts nested attributes for multiple forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord

I have two models, parent and child. I want, while i am creating parent using form, to create children for him. I have following:

parent.rb

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

child.rb

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

_form.rb

```
<%= form_for Parent.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :first_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :first_name %></br>
  <%= f.label :last_name %>
  <%= f.text_field :last_name %></br>
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %></br>
  <%= f.label :phone %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone %></br>

  <%= f.fields_for Child.new do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :first_name %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :first_name %><br>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.fields_for Child.new do |builder| %>
      <%= builder.label :first_name %><br>
      <%= builder.text_field :first_name %><br>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>


<% end %>
```

I want to be able, while i am creating parent, to create one or multiple children for him. If i submit this form, i get message `Unpermitted parameter: child`.

Also in my params hash, when i submit this form, i get only info for child in last child form. How to fix this?

This is my params permit method :

```
params.require(:parent).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, child:{})
```

Comment: Instead of `Child.new` try: `:children` Also in params you have to filter out: `children_attributes:{}` not : `child:{}`, look it up what is being submitted in your params from form in your rails server log.

Comment: I still have 'Unpermitted parameter: child' message

Comment: Like I said, look it up in your rails server log for the params info that has to be permitted.

Answer (score 0):

You are permitting children attributes in a wrong ways, Please use this :

```
params.require(:parent).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, children_attributes: [:first_name])
```

Comment: This would be plural , instead of children_attributes, it would be childrens_attributes

childrens_attributes: [:first_name]